using test -e to check if any file exist in a directory
I want to execute a particular block of code if given file exists.
if ssh user@$host "test -e $file";
...

When $file is a complete file name such /tmp/test1.txt this works fine. However, if I want to check if any file exists in a directory such as $file is /tmp/*, I get
bash: test: too many arguments

Is it possible to use * with test -e, if yes how?

Note that, in addition to the problem you've already noticed (that this misbehaves if $file is a glob that matches multiple files), this also has problems if $file contains whitespace, dollar signs, backticks, quotation marks, backslashes, parentheses, semicolons . . . it's a pretty scary thing to do IMHO.

I prefer use -f or -O for test. maybe you can find -type f , or \double quote/sapostrophe  the FileName

Do any of the answers to "Test whether a glob has any matches in Bash" solve this?

You could use this: ssh user@$host bash <<<"files=($file);test -e \${files[0]}" !

@James using find for replacing test -e  seem disproportionate

To determine if the folder "/tmp" has anything in it, you may use find and grep together:
DIR='/tmp'
if ssh user@host "find $DIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | grep . > /dev/null"; then 
  echo "File found in $DIR of host."
else
  echo "No file found in $DIR of host."
fi

This command fill find the immediate level in the folder to see if there is any file or folder in it.
If you're only concerning files, then:
DIR='/tmp'
if ssh user@host "find $DIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep . > /dev/null"; then 
  echo "File found in $DIR of host."
else
  echo "No file found in $DIR of host."
fi


Use -q switch in grep  instead of redirecting to /dev/null.

find | grep seem overkill for a kind of test -e!!
